# python data crawling using chromedriver : javascript void(0)

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click this login button using chrome driver.
it does not return errors, but the button wasn't clicked and everytime I run the code, I see a little sign on the left of the webpage saying, ' javascript:void(0); '.

Here is my code.
Thanks in advance!

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/XXX/Documents/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://www.hometax.go.kr/websquare/websquare.html?w2xPath=/ui/pp/index.xml')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@class="w2group "]'
    ).click()
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="YOUR_CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")
driver.get('https://www.hometax.go.kr/websquare/websquare.html?w2xPath=/ui/pp/index.xml')

TARGET = 'textbox81212912'

# driver.find_element_by_id("textbox81212912").click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, TARGET))
)
element.click()

input() # wait
```

First, you are seleting the wrong object, by `//*[@class="w2group "]`
this XPath means the first of all objects with the class attribute "w2group" for that page is selected.

Also, the id of "로그인" element is : "textbox81212912"
[image]

Second, use explicitly wait for target element than implicitly wait. This is helpful to prevent unexpected errors like: page load error due to network speed, etc...